# Flatten a list of vectors to a list of floats with fold

Tags: f#

I want to flatten a `Vector3 list` to `float32 list`.

```
[Vector(1.,2.,3.);Vector(1.,2.,3.)] to [1.;2.;3.;1.;2.;3.]
```

I have done it successfully with the following function

```
let rec convert_vec3 (v: Vector3 list) acc =
     match v with
     | [] -> acc
     | x :: xs-> convert_vec3 xs [x.X; x.Y;x.Z] @ acc
```

How would this look with List.fold?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The equivalent of your `convert_vec3` function would be

```
List.fold (fun acc (v:Vector) -> [v.X; v.Y; v.Z] @ acc) [] input
```

But, as mydogisbox mentions, `List.collect` might be better as that will give you the list in the right order, which your `convert_vec3` function and `List.fold` equivalent will not do.

```
List.collect (fun (v:Vector) -> [v.X;v.Y;v.Z]) input
```

Answer (score 3):

The answer of @mydogisbox is good and valid, but you can use `List.fold` as well. Please note that your recursive function gathers the values in reverse order. To avoid that, I would actually recommend `List.foldBack`:

```
([Vector(1.,2.,3.);Vector(1.,2.,3.)], [])
||> List.foldBack (fun v acc -> v.X :: v.Y :: v.Z :: acc) 
// val it : float list = [1.0; 2.0; 3.0; 1.0; 2.0; 3.0]
```

Answer (score 2):

I think what you want is `List.collect` not `List.fold`:

```
> List.collect (fun x->x |> List.map (float32)) [[1.0];[2.0];[3.0]];;
val it : float32 list = [1.0f; 2.0f; 3.0f]]
```

Replace the `(fun x->x |> List.map (float32))` with a mapping between your vectors and a list of the resulting values for that vector